# Cybersource Flex Microform Recurring Payments

Tags: php, cybersource

I'm working with integrating flex microform into an existing php application. I have been able to get individual transactions working, however from that point I am unable to use the token for future transactions as the documentation says should be possible. Is there any way to set up a recurring subscription using the microform such that I could then charge that again in the future?

Comment: If you have questions on how to use a specific service, or if it doesn't work properly, contact the service owners. We're here if you run into some specific programming issue with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flex Microform token is a temporary token that's only useful for a few minutes.

You need to use that to create a permanent Payment Instrument and Customer token. You can then use this in future requests to charge the same credit card.

Our code for making a purchase and getting a permanent token is similar to this:

```
// Save CC
// Based on Samples/Payments/Payments/PaymentWithFlexTokenCreatePermanentTMSToken.php

$token_types = ['customer', 'paymentInstrument', 'billingAddress'];

$processingInformationAuthorizationOptionsInitiator = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsidProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptionsInitiator([
    "credentialStoredOnFile" => true
]);
$processingInformationAuthorizationOptions = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsidProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptions([
    "initiator" => $processingInformationAuthorizationOptionsInitiator,
    "ignoreAvsResult" => true
]);
$processingInformation = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformation([
    'actionList' => ["TOKEN_CREATE"],
    'actionTokenTypes' => $token_types,
    'capture' => $amt != 0,
    "authorizationOptions" => $processingInformationAuthorizationOptions
]);
$orderInformationAmountDetails = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationAmountDetails([
    'currency' => 'USD'
]);
$orderInformationLineItems = [
    new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationLineItems([
        'unitPrice' => round($amt / 100, 2),
        'taxAmount' => $tax,
        'amountIncludesTax' => false
    ])
];
$orderInformationBillTo = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationBillTo(formvars_to_cybersource_billto());
$orderInformation = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformation([
    'amountDetails' => $orderInformationAmountDetails,
    'billTo' => $orderInformationBillTo,
    'lineItems' => $orderInformationLineItems
]);
$buyerInformation = new CyberSource\Model\Tmsv2customersBuyerInformation([
    "merchantCustomerID" => $_SESSION['username'],
    "email" => formvar('i_email')
]);
$tokenInformation = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsTokenInformation(['transientTokenJwt' => formvar('i_provider_token')]);
$requestObj = new CyberSource\Model\CreatePaymentRequest([
    "clientReferenceInformation" => $clientReferenceInformation,
    "processingInformation" => $processingInformation,
    "orderInformation" => $orderInformation,
    "tokenInformation" => $tokenInformation,
    "buyerInformation" => $buyerInformation
]);
$api_instance = new CyberSource\Api\PaymentsApi($api_client);
$apiResponse = $api_instance->createPayment($requestObj);
$customer_id = $apiResponse[0]['tokenInformation']['customer']['id'];
```

`$customer_id` is the permanent customer token that you can save to use in automated purchases. Our code for that looks like:

```
$request = new CyberSource\Model\CreatePaymentRequest([
    "paymentInformation" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformation([
        "customer" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsPaymentInformationCustomer([
            "id" => $customerId,
        ]),
    ]),
    "clientReferenceInformation" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsClientReferenceInformation([
        "code" => sprintf('payment-%s', $requestId)
    ]),
    "orderInformation" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformation([
        "amountDetails" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationAmountDetails([
            "currency" => "USD"
        ]),
        "lineItems" => [
            new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformationLineItems([
                'unitPrice' => round($amount / 100, 2),
                'taxAmount' => $taxAmount,
                'amountIncludesTax' => false
            ])
        ],
    ]),
    "processingInformation" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformation([
        "commerceIndicator" => "internet",
        "authorizationOptions" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptions([
            "initiator" => new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsProcessingInformationAuthorizationOptionsInitiator([
                "type" => "merchant",
            ])
        ]),
        "capture" => true,
    ])
]);

$response = $instance->createPayment($request);
```

Comment: using similar code, I get null for the $apiResponse[0]['tokenInformation'] hitting the apitest end point. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Check if there was an error in the response.